# Sum Numbers With Delimiter By Formula in Excel 2019

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a cell with text as `0.4-2-10-0.5`. How can I create formula or function using VBA to sum every element at cell is 0.4+2+10+0.5 =`12.9` ?
I tried formula from https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3959-excel-sum-numbers-with-commas.html. However That's wrong with my this case.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've tagged `Excel 2010`, P.b's `FILTERXML` set-up won't be an option for you. Try:

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",25)),1+25*(ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,1+LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))))-1),25)))`

Comment: Nice one. I saw that as well, but the title mentioned Excel 2019, so posted it anyway. Yours does not only work with prior versions of Excel, it would also work on systems other than Windows.

Comment: Ah, good point. Title says 2019, you're right!

Answer (score 2):

Formula solution would be:
`=SUM(FILTERXML("<y><z>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","</z><z>")&"</z></y>","//z"))` where `A1` would contain the given text.
Side note: this formula `FILTERXML` only works on Windows systems.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine for me. Keep out, your locale might interpret the dot differently:

```
Sub test()
Dim s As String
s = "0.4-2-10-0.5"
a = Split(s, "-")
Dim sum As Double
sum = 0
For Each t In a
  sum = sum + CDbl(t)
Next t
End Sub
```